# Generalized Hough Transform and OpenCv

Tags: c++, opencv, hough-transform

I’m looking for an OpenCv implementation of Generalized Hough Transform, or at least something in c++.
Despite I searched for a while, I’ve not been able to find nothing interesting.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I hope this [Generalized Hough Transform code](https://web.archive.org/web/20190215081959/http://www.itriacasa.it:80/generalized-hough-transform/) is what you are looking for.
There is a very simple tutorial as well and some instructions.